# Dar formato a XML desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Hice un script que lista los articulos en un archivo XML para que lo puedan sincronizar con Facebook, el problema es que no puedo darle el formato que me piden que deberia ser asi:

Formato XML que debo obtener

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
  <metadata>
     <ref_application_id>160825592398259</ref_application_id>
     <ref_asset_id>0NyxiGDvt8owUmpzzv09DU1I2W4w3RqT</ref_asset_id>
  </metadata>
  <title>tienda</title>
  <link>http://tienda.com</link>
  <description>Productos varios de tienda.com</description>

  <item>
    <g:id>1736</g:id>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    <g:condition>New</g:condition>
    <g:description>PC Gamer MX 123</g:description>
    <g:image_link>https://tienda.com/image/image.jpg</g:image_link>
    <g:link>https://tienda.com/producto?@producto=1736</g:link>
    <g:title>PC Gamer MX 123</g:title>
    <g:price>ARS 3350,00</g:price>
    <g:identifier_exists>no</g:identifier_exists>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

genera_xml.php

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tienda', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$codefile = '1s6Ai00Hw'; // id de usuario

$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY idp DESC"); // lista de productos

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true; 
$g = $xml->createElement('channel');
$xml->appendChild($g);

while ($row = $list->fetch()) {
    $pro = $xml->createElement('item'); 
    $g->appendChild($pro);

    $titulo = $xml->createElement("g:title", $row['titulo']); 
    $g->appendChild($titulo);

    $imagen = $xml->createElement("g:image", $row['imagen']); 
    $g->appendChild($imagen);
}

$xml->save($codefile.".xml");
?>
```

Formato que obtengo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <channel>
   <item/>
    <g:title>Mother Gigabyte</g:title>
    <g:image>https://picsum.photos/id/0/600</g:image>
   <item/>
    <g:title>PC Atom TX-520</g:title>
    <g:image>https://picsum.photos/id/0/600</g:image>
  </channel>
```

Agradezco de antemano.

Comment: De entrada te recomiendo usar SimpleXMLElement en lugar de DOM, tan solo por el manejo de espacios de nombres.

Comment: Entiendo, y leyendo la documentación dentro de `SimpleXMLElement()` debo pasar una variable que contenga el formato XML, si mal no entiendo. Pero como paso un `while` para pasar datos de la base de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `SimpleXmlElement` instanciándolo con el nodo raíz:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement('<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0"/>');
$g = $xml->getDocNamespaces()['g']; // Espacio de nombres que usaremos para productos

$channel = $xml->addChild('channel');
$channel->addChild('metadata');
$channel->metadata->addChild('ref_application_id',160825592398259);
$channel->addChild('title','tienda');

// Aquí tu ciclo para productos:
$item = $channel->addChild('item');
$item->addChild( 'id', 1736, $g ); // El tercer parámetro es el namespace
$item->addChild( 'availability', 'in stock', $g );

echo $xml->asXml();
```

Resultado:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
   <channel>
      <metadata>
         <ref_application_id>160825592398259</ref_application_id>
      </metadata>
      <title>tienda</title>
      <item>
         <g:id>1736</g:id>
         <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
      </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 2):

Algunos errores que puedo notar:

Empiezas a añadir nodos con:

```
$g = $xml->createElement('channel');
$xml->appendChild($g);
```

El nodo raíz no es `channel` sino `rss`. Te lo saltaste. Hay que empezar por ahí.

Más abajo (recordemos que `$g` es el nodo  `channel`)

```
    $pro = $xml->createElement('item'); 
    $g->appendChild($pro);
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, creaste `item` como hijo de `channel`. Pero luego:

```
$titulo = $xml->createElement("g:title", $row['titulo']); 
$g->appendChild($titulo);
```

Pones `g:title` como hijo de  `channel`, pero debe ser hijo de `item`.

El resultado de lo que pusiste es que las propiedades del producto quedan como siblings del nodo  `ìtem`, el cual a su vez queda vacío.

```
<item></item>
<g:title>PC Atom TX-520</g:title>
<g:image>https://picsum.photos/id/0/600</g:image>
```

Al guardar eso, `<item></item>`  se convierte en `<item/>` a menos que lo guardes con la constante `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`

```
    $doc->saveXML(null,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

#### Solución Propuesta

Suponiendo que tu consulta diera en cada fila un arreglo asociativo que describe el producto (voy a poner dos productos y solo dos atributos)

```
    $productos = [
        ['id' => '1736', 'title' => 'PC Gamer MX 123',],
        ['id' => '1234', 'title' => 'Notebook livianito y caro']
    ];
```

Creamos el documento e insertamos su nodo raíz,

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$rss = $doc->createElement('rss');
$rss->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
$rss->setAttribute('version', '2.0');
$doc->appendChild($rss);
```

Creamos channel como hijo del nodo `raíz`,

```
$channel = $doc->createElement('channel');
$rss->appendChild($channel);
```

Que para todo efecto es igual que operar sobre el documentElement

```
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($channel);
```

Creamos metadata como hijo de `channel`, y `ref_asset_id` como hijo de `metadata`,  y Thorin hijo de Thrain hijo de Thor, etc.

```
    $metadata=$doc->createElement('metadata');
    $channel->appendChild($metadata);
    $ref=$doc->createElement('ref_asset_id','0NyxiGDvt8owUmpzzv09DU1I2W4w3RqT');
    $metadata->appendChild($ref);
```

**Llegamos finalmente a la iteración sobre la consulta de productos**

Iteramos sobre el resultado de la query, y en cada iteración creamos un `item`  y lo añadimos al `channel`. Luego por cada llave de la fila obtenida, creamos un nodo con prefijo `g` y lo añadimos **al item.**

```
foreach ($productos as $productAttributes) {
  $item = $doc->createElement('item');
  $channel->appendChild($item);
  foreach ($productAttributes as $key => $value) {
    $productAttribute = $doc->createElementNS('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0', 'g:' . $key, $value);
    $item->appendChild($productAttribute);
  }
}
```

Al guardar tendremos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <metadata>
      <ref_asset_id>0NyxiGDvt8owUmpzzv09DU1I2W4w3RqT</ref_asset_id>
    </metadata>
    <item>
      <g:id>1736</g:id>
      <g:title>PC Gamer MX 123</g:title>
    </item>
    <item>
      <g:id>1234</g:id>
      <g:title>Notebook livianito y caro</g:title>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**[(Ver playground de ejemplo)](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/9280cef3-4dad-4fa6-b7f5-43d266a60dc3)**

#### Podría usar `loadXML`?

Seguro que sí, pero el documento que se carga con loadXML pisa lo que se tenga cargado, incluyendo el encoding del documento.

```
    $doc1 = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $doc1->formatOutput = true;
    $doc1->loadXML(
        '<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0"/>'
    );
    dump($doc1->saveXML());
```

Imprime

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0"/>
```

Mientras que el método largo y tedioso respeta el encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0"/>
```

#### Declaración de los namespaces

Como en tu pregunta no estás añadiendo el nodo `rss` no hay dónde declarar el namespace que afecta a los hijos de `item`. Pero lo importante es que si el nodo raíz tiene un namespace y prefijo:

```
$rss->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
```

Lo correcto sería que los nodos afectados por ese prefijo `g` se declarasen como:

```
  $doc->createElementNS('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0', 'g:' . $key, $value);
```

Y no como

```
  $doc->createElement('g:' . $key, $value);
```

Aunque en apariencia son la misma cosa, los namespaces te permiten tener "cortes" de elementos que tienen un propósito en común, un significado relacionado, o derechamente deben ser interpretados de otra manera que el nodo que los contiene, por ejemplo a la hora de validar schema o canonicalizar.

En este caso, si yo declaro un producto con NS y otro sin:

```
        $itemConNS = $doc->createElement('item');
        $channel->appendChild($itemConNS);
        foreach ($productos[0] as $key => $value) {
            $productAttribute = $doc->createElementNS('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0', 'g:' . $key, $value);
            $itemConNS->appendChild($productAttribute);
        }
  

        $itemSinNS = $doc->createElement('item');
        $channel->appendChild($itemSinNS);
        foreach ($productos[1] as $key => $value) {
            $productAttribute = $doc->createElement('g:' . $key, $value);
            $itemSinNS->appendChild($productAttribute);
        }
```

Guardar el XML como string efectivamente los lleva a ser lo mismo:

```
<item>
  <g:id>1736</g:id>
  <g:title>PC Gamer MX 123</g:title>
</item>
<item>
  <g:id>1234</g:id>
  <g:title>Notebook livianito y caro</g:title>
</item>
```

Pero si yo quisiera eliminar ese prefijo `g`  porque ya no lo necesito o lo que sea, me bastaría con:

```
    $doc->documentElement->removeAttributeNS('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0', 'g');
```

Si ahora guardo el documento, mi intento de quitar el prefijo sólo habrá surtido efecto en el nodo que fue declarado con idem. El otro seguirá con prefijo `g` para siempre.

[Ver playground de ejemplo.](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/12748373-4aa9-4737-b9b4-a71ca4eaeb8a)